# Mysql query Solution

Tags: php, mysql

Dear Friends I have a table (code_bit_table) in which I have articles stores. Each article has SUBJECT and then each article has TITLE and TAGS. I want to search the table based on any letter in the title OR TAGS fields BUT with in a single SUBJECT. eg I want to search ONLY PHP and with in PHP i will like to check if the TITLE OR the TAGS field contain some text (eg array).

The problem is that my query return other subjects as well. It may be a very simple problem but has puzzled me a lot

> ```
>  SELECT * FROM code_bit_table WHERE `subject` = 'PHP'  AND `tags` LIKE 
>    '%text%' OR `title` LIKE '%text%'
> ```

The query works fine but why it return other subjects like jQuery etc also present in the same table.

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses are your friend.

```
SELECT *
FROM code_bit_table
WHERE `subject` = 'PHP'
    AND (`tags` LIKE '%text%'
          OR `title` LIKE '%text%'
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     SELECT * FROM code_bit_table WHERE `subject` = 'PHP'  AND (`tags` LIKE 
   '%text%' OR `title` LIKE '%text%')
```

Answer (score 1):

You must put opening closing brackets '(' & ')' for `OR` part to override the precedence of `AND` operator as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM code_bit_table 
WHERE `subject` = 'PHP'  AND 
      (`tags` LIKE '%text%' OR `title` LIKE '%text%');
```

Answer (score 1):

you must group the `tags` and `title`.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM code_bit_table 
 WHERE `subject` = 'PHP'  AND 
       (`tags` LIKE '%text%' OR 
        `title` LIKE '%text%');
```